# How to filter Dictionary of Array Swift3.0?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I've an Dictionary which contains Array and that Array has another Dictionary ant it also has another array. How do I get the last array by using 'Dictionary.Filter'.
For Example

> Dict1->Array1->Dict2->Array2.

Here I need

> Array2

I want to get "DeviceLsit" Array [image]

Comment: you dont get the array using `filter`, you will still end up with the top-level dictionary with possibly less content. Just write something like `dirctionary[key1][index1][key2]`, that should get you the array2.

Comment: Can you provide a sample??

Comment: He did provide a sample.

Comment: @DuncanC please check it now

Comment: @Rishab: for clear idea i've added plist image please check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out! Based on your screenshot, I have managed to achieve it!

```
func filterArray() {
    let dictPlist = Dictionary<String, Any>()
    if let arrKeyName = dictPlist["key"] as? Array<Dictionary<String, Any>> {
    let yourSecondArray = arrKeyName.filter({ (keyDict) -> Bool in
            guard let _ = keyDict["keyName"] as? Array<Any> else {
                return false
            }
            return true
        })
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

if you want array of DeviceLists you can got through categories and get device lists

```
let root: [String: Any] = ["Categories": [ ["deviceList": ["1","2","3","4"]], ["deviceList": ["5","6","7","8"]]  ]]

if let categories = root["Categories"] as? [Any] {

    var deviceLists: [String] = []
    for cat in categories {
        if let cat = cat as? [String: Any], let deviceNames = cat["deviceList"] as? [String] {
            deviceLists.append(contentsOf: deviceNames)
        }
    }
    print(deviceLists)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**here is the short anser :**

Assume that your desired Array has Any Type. you can make it as you want like String , Int etc...!

```
let dict = [String:[[String:[Any]]]]() 
let arr = dict.flatMap({($0.value).flatMap({($0.values)})}).last
print(arr) <-- your desired Array
```